# Druid HTTP query interval that ends now

Tags: nosql, bigdata, druid

I have a HTTP query which I use for getting all customers between the 1.5.2018 and 7.5.2018. Can I somehow edit this to get all customers from 1.5.2018 to NOW? I couldn't find this in the documentation, so I assumed the ending interval is required and has to be specific. Can someone help me edit it? Or do I have to take care of getting the actual date in an application?

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": "customers",
  "granularity": "all",
  "intervals": [ "2018-05-07T00:00:00.000/2018-05-21T00:00:00.000" ]
}
```

Comment: how are you accessing these HTTP ? which client you are using ?

Comment: I'm using REST API... I know that in application I can simply get the current time and put it on the right side of the interval

Answer (score 0):

The time interval value will be like below

```
"intervals": "2018-05-07T00:00:00.000/2018-05-21T00:00:00.000"
```

No square brackets. Below is an sample topN query -

```
{"aggregations":[{"name":"count","type":"count"},{"fieldName":"fname1","name":"fname1","type":"longSum"},{"fieldName":"fname2","name":"fname2","type":"longSum"}],"dataSource":"xxx","dimension":"dim1","granularity":"all","intervals":"2018-05-16T00:00:00.000/2018-05-17T00:00:00.000","metric":"count","queryType":"topN","threshold":4}
```